# Updating a textbox using no input controls

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a windows form application which consists of a bunch of controls, but more specifically, two `textBoxes`. One of them is read only. The read only `textBox` value is supposed to be the same as the `textBox` that the user can type into.

So if the user types "Hello World" into `textBox` A, the value in `textBox` B should be automatically updated to "Hello World".

How do I go about doing this? I know I just need to set the text values, I'm just not sure where I place the code to get it done automatically rather than executed when a button is click or something along those lines.

Comment: Windows form application? I don't see what jQuery has to do with it?

Comment: I don't see how "Windows Form" follows from your question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: "I have a form application" is a *hint*, although I agree that it could have been clearer.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: That's why I only said it was a hint :) I think most people would specifically call out the "web" part of a web forms application rather than just refer to it as a "form application".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want textBoxB to be updated as soon as the text of textBoxA is changed (i.e immediately after the user press a key in textBoxA) the event is TextChanged:

```
    this.textBoxA.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBoxA_TextChanged);

    private void textBoxA_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxB.Text = textBoxA.Text;
    }
```

If you prefer to update the text in textBoxB only after the user has finished to edit textBoxA, you should use the Leave event:

```
    this.textBoxA.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBoxA_Leave);

    private void textBoxA_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxB.Text = textBoxA.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

TextChanged event:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
        }
```

Comment: Plus, don't forget to register the event to your `textBox`.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
writableTextBox.TextChanged += delegate {
    readonlyTextBox.Text = writableTextBox.Text;
};
```

In other words, whenever the text in one textbox changes, update the other. This uses the [`Control.TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event.

Comment: Nice one-line solution. Not the simplest for _happyguy_ to understand what events are though :)

Comment: @Leito: Are you assuming that the OP doesn't already know about events?

Comment: I _do_ assume, yes. `TextChanged` is one of the first event I encountered when learning events - and seems logical. But I can be wrong :)

Comment: @Leito: I don't think it's *that* core an event. If the OP were asking how to react when a button was clicked, that would be a clearer hint, I think :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you need:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter (better?) than the event approach is using winform's databinding. Just use this right after the `InitializeComponents` call:

```
readonlyTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", writableTextBox, "Text");
```